# Remove cookies from static requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, cookies

I am trying to optimize performance for my ASP MVC4 website. One of the suggestions from google pagespeed is, to serve my static files from a cookieless domain.

From what I have read so far, it is possible to achieve this by creating 2 websites ( one for your site www.site.com) and one for your static files (www.static.site.com) both pointing to the same files. You should then set up the static site to be stateless.

Is there any other way to get around this without having to create 2 websites in IIS.

It seems like such a big waste to have to deploy my project twice to have static files with no cookies

Answer (score 0):

Why are you deploying the project twice? You could deploy it once and map virtual directories from the stateless domain/sub domain to your physical directories.

Comment: I still need to set up 2 sites, I have changed the question to explain better. The site needs to be on https as well, so now I need to buy 2 certs, because my company does not want to pay for wildcard cert.